# How to compute the position of the 4th corner of a rectangle?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have 3 corners of an axis aligned box, I must find the 4th corner.

How can I compute it more efficiently:

```cpp
if (loc[0].first != loc[1].first && loc[0].first != loc[2].first)
    x = loc[0].first;
else if (loc[1].first != loc[0].first && loc[1].first != loc[2].first)
    x = loc[1].first;
else
    x = loc[2].first;

if (loc[0].second != loc[1].second && loc[0].second != loc[2].second)
    y = loc[0].second;
else if (loc[1].second != loc[0].second && loc[1].second!=loc[2].second)
    y = loc[1].second;
else 
    y = loc[2].second;
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: nothing in the posted code checks if a number is odd or even. Please post a [mcve] and try to explain what the code is supposed to do

Comment: i have a 2d array which has three astrisks scattered forming and incomplete rectangle so i must find the 4th place where the last one should be to make a full rectangle

Comment: i dont want to find odd or even i want to find the different number

Comment: And there are always two equal and one different number? In that case, replace `if(...) if(...) ...` with `if(...) else if(...) ...` so that you can stop looking once you found the "odd one out"

Comment: yes i will do that, but is there a better way?

Comment: It only takes 2 points to define an axis-aligned rectangle.  It's a problem that you have 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have 2 identical (integral) numbers and a third one, `xor` might give you the expected one:

```cpp
x = loc[0].first  ^ loc[1].first  ^ loc[2].first;
y = loc[0].second ^ loc[1].second ^ loc[2].second;
```

if type is not integral (so no xor), it seems more readable to check for equality (that also does one check for equality instead of 2 checks for inequality by test):

```cpp
if (loc[0].first == loc[1].first)
    x = loc[2].first;
else if (loc[0].first == loc[2].first)
    x = loc[1].first;
else // loc[1].first == loc[2].first
    x = loc[0].first;
```

Comment: oh right, xor only pick if exactly one is different right?

Comment: `value ^ value == 0`, so pair of equal values simplify itself.

Comment: never thought of it this way

Comment: The `xor` approach is very elegant. Never thought of it in this context before. Thank you for sharing.

Comment: ow! my eyes! my eyes!

Answer (score 0):

If the points are guaranteed to be perfectly aligned vertically or horizontally, the fourth corner is found at the unique abscissa and unique ordinate.

```
if X0 == X1:
    X3= X2
elif X0 == X2:
    X3= X1
else:
    X3= X0
```

You can't do this in less than two comparisons, because the outcome depends on the three values.

Same code on `Y`, independently. Or, you can even spare a comparison on `Y`, because if two `X`'s are known to be equal, the corresponding `Y`'s are perforce different. Hence on average a total of 8/3 comparisons.

---

If you are after the ordered axis-aligned bounding box, take the minimum and maximum of the abscissas and ordinates separately.